# Create raster map from numpy array

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy

I want to create a raster map from a Numpy array from arcgis. I am using arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster() function to convert. But it is throwing following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sidath\Desktop\generateMap.py", line 179, in <module>
    newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(in_array=myFinal)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 2299, in NumPyArrayToRaster
    return _NumPyArrayToRaster(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Cannot create raster for numpy array.
```

Following is my code snippet

```
myFinal = np.array(myFinal)
newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(in_array=myFinal)   
newRaster.save("rastwe.tif")
```

Comment: What is `myFinal` set to *before* you try to make a NumPy array from it?

Comment: Have you set the work space for arcpy? If not you need to provide the full path when you save the raster.